# asp.net MVC5 handling errors inside child action method in parent view -- would like to redirect to error page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm still somewhat new to ASP.NET MVC so I hope my question is clear. In my project I have a parent view, that renders partial views inside the parent view by calling @Html.Action(controller action name) inside the parent view.

My goal is that if the controller action that returns the partial view fails, I would like the application to redirect to my error page. This works perfectly fine for my controller actions that are returning full views by doing the following: return RedirectToAction("Index", "ErrorHandler", null). However in the controller methods returning partial views (that are invoked with @Html.Action inside parent View), this returns error that child action cannot do redirect.

I also tried doing, return View("~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml"), inside controller action that returns partial view. This doesn't throw an error but results in displaying the error page inside the parent page. That is not ideal as I stated earlier, my goal is to have application fully redirect to error page.

Here is some code. Let me know if you want to see more of my code:
Inside Parent View
`@Html.Action("LoadEmployeeNames")`

Controller method below:

```
public ActionResult LoadEmployeeNames()
{
string ManageRSVPApplicationName = 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManageRSVPApplicationName"];
Log log = new Log(ManageRSVPApplicationName);
try
{
 int applicationId = 
 Convert.ToInt32(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["ApplicationId"]);
 Application application = new Application();
            application.ApplicationId = applicationId;
            if (DataBase.PopulateInviteeList(ref application, ref log))
            {
                List<EmployeeDropDownOption> employees = new List<EmployeeDropDownOption>();
                if(false)
                //if (EmployeeData.LoadEmployees(ref employees, application.InviteeList, ref log))
                {
                    string currUserAccountName = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
                    EmployeeDropDownOption currEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(t => t.AccountName.Trim().ToLower() == currUserAccountName.Trim().ToLower());
                    ViewBag.CurrentUserIdentity = (currEmployee == null) ? "" : currEmployee.EmployeeID.ToString() + ":" + currEmployee.DisplayName;
                    int currOfficeId = 0;
                    if (currEmployee != null)
                    {
                        DataBase.GetOfficeId(currEmployee.Office, ref currOfficeId, ref log);
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestOffice"]))
                        {
                            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentOffice"] = currEmployee.Office;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentOffice"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestOffice"];
                        }

                    }

                    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentOfficeId"] = currOfficeId;

                    EmployeeDropDown employeeNameDD = new EmployeeDropDown(employees);

                    return PartialView("~/Views/RSVP/RSVP/SelectEmployeeName.cshtml", employeeNameDD);
                }

            }
            log.Capture(Log.LogLevel.Error, "Unable to load employees when " + User.Identity.Name + " attempted to view RSVP application " + applicationId);
            return View("~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Capture(Log.LogLevel.Error, "Unable to load employees when " + User.Identity.Name + " attempted to view RSVP application ");
            log.Capture(Log.LogLevel.Error, e);
            return View("~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the post, please?

Comment: We definitely need to see some of your code from both your parent view and your controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

In general avoid using try catch block in controller actions, it make error handling process hard to maintain. instead use action filters to separate error handling code from code that define application normal flow
here is a simple custom error handler filter

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "CustomError",
            MasterName = Master,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

    }
}
```

And use the filter on controller level or individual action as follow

```
[CustomHandleErrorAttribute]
public ActionResult LoadEmployeeNames()
{
    string ManageRSVPApplicationName =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManageRSVPApplicationName"];
    Log log = new Log(ManageRSVPApplicationName);

    int applicationId = Convert.ToInt32(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["ApplicationId"]);
    Application application = new Application();
    application.ApplicationId = applicationId;
    if (DataBase.PopulateInviteeList(ref application, ref log))
    {
        List<EmployeeDropDownOption> employees = new List<EmployeeDropDownOption>();
        if (false)
        //if (EmployeeData.LoadEmployees(ref employees, application.InviteeList, ref log))
        {
            string currUserAccountName = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
            EmployeeDropDownOption currEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(t => t.AccountName.Trim().ToLower() == currUserAccountName.Trim().ToLower());
            ViewBag.CurrentUserIdentity = (currEmployee == null) ? "" : currEmployee.EmployeeID.ToString() + ":" + currEmployee.DisplayName;
            int currOfficeId = 0;
            if (currEmployee != null)
            {
                DataBase.GetOfficeId(currEmployee.Office, ref currOfficeId, ref log);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestOffice"]))
                {
                    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentOffice"] = currEmployee.Office;
                }
                else
                {
                    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentOffice"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestOffice"];
                }

            }

            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentOfficeId"] = currOfficeId;

            EmployeeDropDown employeeNameDD = new EmployeeDropDown(employees);

            return PartialView("~/Views/RSVP/RSVP/SelectEmployeeName.cshtml", employeeNameDD);
        }

    }
    log.Capture(Log.LogLevel.Error, "Unable to load employees when " + User.Identity.Name + " attempted to view RSVP application " + applicationId);
    return View("~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml");


}
```

Finally add CustomError.cshtml to Views/Shared folder

Comment: What exactly is OnException method above doing? How would I redirect user to the app's universal error page in this method? And will this work for controller actions returning child actions (called by @Html.Action in parent view)? Also, what if in controller action above, DataBase.PopulateInviteeList() method returns false but controller action doesn't throw exception?

Comment: Ok I think understand method redirects user to custom error page. Currently my error page is located at "~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml", can I use this error page or does it have to be located in shared folder?  Also, what about when method has an error but doesn't throw exception?

Comment: if any Exception happen in controller action this custom filter attribute return CustomError.cshtml content as the response to request , and it will work for child actions too

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is it possible to call this method if no exception is thrown, for example, if DataBase.PopulateInviteeList() method returns false ?

Comment: the flow of request doesnt change if  no exception happen in processing request.